# Postgres | Execute delete cte after insert cte

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, rdbms

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
    id      bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    from_id bigint NOT NULL,
    to_id   bigint NOT NULL,
    comments text NOT NULL,
    data    jsonb  NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_unique_idx ON product(from_id, to_id, comments);
```

With the following data:

```
insert into product(from_id, to_id, comments, data) values
(1, 2, 'bla', '{}'),
(2, 3, 'bla', '{}'),
(1, 3, 'bla', '{}'),
(3, 2, 'bla', '{}'),
(2, 1, 'bla', '{}'),
(3, 1, 'bla', '{}');
```

Now, I want to insert new records that will update from_id & to_id with a given collection, for example replace all from_id & to_ids [1,2] with 3 (also delete where from_id == to_id), because of the `UNIQUE INDEX` I do it via `insert` and then `delete` all other rows:

```
with
   insert_stmt_to_id AS (
      insert into product
         (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
         (select from_id,3,comments,data from product
           where to_id in (1,2))
         ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING),
   insert_stmt_from_id AS (
      insert into product
         (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
         (select 3,to_id,comments,data from product
           where from_id in (1,2))
         ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING),
   delete_stmt AS (DELETE from product where to_id in (1,2) or from_id in (1,2) RETURNING *)
select * from delete_stmt
```

But after `select * from product`, I get (there are [1, 2] in from+it\to_id):

[image]

How is it?

Comment: don't use WItH clause use a transaction

Comment: @nbk, can you explain with sample?

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are trying to achieve. Is the expected result, that all rows have `(from_id, to_id) = (3,3)` after this? Also: a column named  `comments`  as part of a unique constraint seems a bit strange

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  maybe I didn't mentioned it, duplicates should removed as well. about the comments, yes, it's part of the unique constraint

Comment: So what exactly is the result you are looking for?

Comment: given those records, nothing

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to do so:

```
with
   delete_duplicates as (
      delete from product where
         (from_id in (1,2) and to_id in (1,2)) or
         (from_id = 3 and to_id in (1,2)) or
         (from_id in (1,2) and to_id  = 3)
      RETURNING id),
   insert_stmt_from_id AS (
      insert into product
         (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
         (select 3,to_id,comments,data from product
           where from_id in (1,2) and not id in (select id from delete_duplicates))
       ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING RETURNING id),
   insert_stmt_to_id AS (
      insert into product
         (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
         (select from_id,3,comments,data from product
           where to_id in (1,2) and not id in (select id from delete_duplicates))
       ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING RETURNING id),
   delete_leftovers_stmt AS (DELETE from product where from_id in (1,2) or to_id in (1,2) RETURNING id)
select id from delete_duplicates union select id from delete_leftovers_stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html), so that all commands are run in an extra state and it will  give you an answer with only one as result

> ```
> BEGIN;
>       insert into product
>          (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
>          (select from_id,3,comments,data from product
>            where to_id in (1,2))
>          ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING;
>
>       insert into product
>          (from_id, to_id, comments, data)
>          (select 3,to_id,comments,data from product
>            where from_id in (1,2))
>          ON CONFLICT (from_id, to_id, comments) DO NOTHING;
>     DELETE from product where to_id in (1,2) or from_id in (1,2);         
> COMMIT;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 1 rows affected
>
> ✓
>
> 6 rows affected
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM product
> ```
>
> ```
> id | from_id | to_id | comments | data
> -: | ------: | ----: | :------- | :---
>  8 |       3 |     3 | bla      | {}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ecfbd5c28719c4d8e402b82ce302b418)*